# how can i optimize main.js size?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have a Vue.JS application. I'm creating it using webpack. I'm getting large main.js size after application build. (9 Mb).

I have any packages. But I'm getting large main.js size after creating empty application, too. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: you could use plugins like webpack-bundle-analyzer to check why the bundle size is large

Comment: (1) Did you have Uglify in your building pipeline (in other words: Does your code get minified?) (2) Did you add externals for common libraries that might already be cached by the client (i.e. Vue itself) ?

Comment: I didn't use Uglify. And I didn't use optimization libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uglifyjs-webpack-plugin, compression-webpack-plugin to optimize your bundle size.

Here is my full [code](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

Example:

```
optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: false,
                extractComments: 'all',
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: true,
                    output: null
                }
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessorOptions: {
                    safe: true,
                    discardComments: {
                        removeAll: true,
                    },
                },
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            test: /\.(js|css)/
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
```

So UglifyJsPlugin help you to minify and uglify js code. CompressionPlugin help you compress your js file into gzip extension.

But I would recommend you use webpack-bundle-analyzer to check the bundle size affect final build

Answer (score 0):

**There are several ways of optimising your main file and application performance.** All of them works, but some might be not suitable for your case.

1. **Code splitting and lazy load components**.
   In my case I solved problem by using code splitting and lazy loading components. 
   It turned main.js into very small one and other files are loaded when becomes visible. 
   Check [this](https://medium.com/js-dojo/3-code-splitting-patterns-for-vuejs-and-webpack-b8fff1ea0ba4) article about code splitting and [this](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/lazy-load-vue-components-when-they-become-visible/) one about lazy load in Vue.js. It is very common approach in libraries like React or Vue.js.
2. **Optimising libraries**. No much to add, check if is possible to pull function instead of whole library (like in lodash) or use native implementation instead of external one. Unused *npm*s also does not makes your main file lighter. Even if now you don't have much packages optimising them in future will make a difference.
3. **Minifying and uglyfing**. Most common and most important practice not only because of performance reasons but also because of security. Those two webpack plugins are the most popular webpack plugins at all:

   - [UglifyJS](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) - for JS
   - [MiniCSS](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) - for CSS
4. **Webpack optimisation**. Webpack knows thousands of tricks how to make your bundle smaller, but from time to time it might be your false friend. Remember to define how to resolve some dependencies, for example by pointing to proper node_module or library. It can looks like, where alias for lodash saved me a lot of **kBs**.

   resolve: {
   modules: ['app', 'node_modules'],
   extensions: [
     '.js',
   ],
   mainFields: [
     'browser',
   ],
   alias: {
     'lodash-es': 'lodash'
   }
   }
5. **Code responsibly**.

The best way to understand your problem is to analyse main.js, you can achieve it by adding Bundle Analyzer Plugin to your webpack config into plugins. It should looks like:

```
new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    reportFilename: 'report.html',
    analyzerMode: 'static'
  })
```

Look into [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) if you want to adjust it somehow. Interactive report is awesome.

Comment: I tried to to like you wrote, but I didn't get result what I expected. Code splitting make  an application to work like MPA. Uglyfing already embedded to webpack. I didn't see it. Also I'm trying to to use webpack optimization, but I'm getting an error `'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "event-source-polyfill"'`. I cant't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your error means that you need to install this NPM, by `npm install event-source-polyfill --save-dev`. You need to understand your problem first, provide some conclusions from analysing BundleAnalyzer report. If you have problems with using it check my answer or documentation - it's super easy.